# How to use Telegram API Methods

Tags: telegram

Please look at these Telegram API Methods: https://core.telegram.org/methods

How should I use them and by which programming language?!

Are they API and can I use them in URL?

Comment: It is obviously API. Due to the first line of your provided source!

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. We don't leave this site to go find out what you're asking, and we don't find languages to use to access an API or give tutorials regarding how to use that API. Before posting your next question, be sure to thoroughly and carefully read [ask]. (Much more carefully than you read the name of the Telegram **API**, for instance, because it's clearly an **API** or it wouldn't have **API** in its name.)

Comment: @mahdi what programming language are you comfortable with?

Comment: some Bot Code Examples for different languages : https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples

Comment: @Mohammadb he asked for Telegram, Not bots

Answer (score 3):

`Telegram` offer two kinds of APIs for developers. The Bot API allows you to easily create programs that use `Telegram` messages for an interface. The `Telegram` API allows you to build your own customised `Telegram` clients.

I would assume that you are referring to the Bot API, and [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) is where you can see the list of languages supported with their respective wrapper created by the community, otherwise you can create your own with the API as the Bot API is an HTTP-based interface created for developers keen on building bots for Telegram. The language supported includes `PHP`, `Python`, `Java`, `C#`, `Ruby`, `Go`, `Lua`, `Node.js` and `Haskell`.